# Allow more specific positioning of hats?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

The hats seem to be designed for passport-photo-like avatars. Perhaps it would be better if you could choose where exactly it fits?

Comment: I think it's a good fit for you :)

Comment: your image picture is super cool...

Comment: @WinterBash Thanks :)

Comment: ahha kolink your image is truly awesome .. i wish i could get one like yours ...

Comment: Hey, how to get my own hat too?

Answer (score 28):

Sorry, but right now that's not really technically feasible. We apologize for the inconvenience.

That said! Part of the fun of this event is how silly we're all going to look, and how we can tweak our gravatars to make the hats look *as awesome as possible!* So go with it, maybe bust out the Photoshop (or, if you're cheap like me, MS Paint) and, as [Tim Gunn](http://youtu.be/RbMLXEAHTTo) would say -- make it work!

Comment: Side-question: Why do I not have the "Constantipolitan" hat on SO? I posted on Meta, and that's the listed requirement. I need that fez! Fezzes are cool!

Comment: @Kolink Fezzes are super cool! Right now, there's a bit of a delay between MSO and SO hattening. Give it a bit of time -- we're working on reducing that delay!

Comment: Understood. Thank you! I'm totes going to change my Gravatar to my fez-wearing Shinx character (#[=^_^=]#)

Comment: It's very hattening to know that it is at least happening.

Comment: Too bad SO hasn't implemented my favorite feature request of all times : let us use somethings else than the embarrassing gravatar service...

Comment: **One of the last known habitats for real unicorns should not be using technical feasibility as a metric for feature development!** Thankfully [the devs seem to have better priorities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211798/145951) than you do.

Answer (score 20):

**Beginning with the 2013 hat season, hats may be manually positioned!**

How to make your unicorn* happy in three easy steps:

1. Open the winterbash control console and choose your headgear of preference.
2. Drag the topping to the desired location relative to your [unicorn gravatar](http://blog.gravatar.com/tag/unicornify/).
3. Hit the 'Wear hat' button to officially don the accessory.

<sub>* Alternatively, your face.</sub>

Comment: Oh ***SWEET***!

Comment: Can we resize them too?

Comment: Can we rotate them too ?

Comment: Can we change them into other hats too? I want a Mac Classic for a hat!

Comment: @MrLister You can swap them out for any hat you have earned for you're collection. If you want the Mac hat see the Winterbash site for the qualifications for acquiring it.

Comment: @Caleb Oh, sorry, I thought I was being funny. I can never earn the Hello World hat now, can I.