# Can we resize hats?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

Can we have the ability to resize or move the hats up or down?

I had to remake my gravatar so that my hat would fit.

^_^

[image: hats galore!]

Comment: Don't think it's worth the effort. Those who really care (like you :)) will just remake their gravatars.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hehe things like the cupcake, cheese and bowtie look quite funny on me. I don't wanna have to remake my gravar on every new hat :-P

Comment: Agreed. I don't have the original AI file handy to re-do mine at the moment.

Comment: Hats can [now be repositioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211798/145951) although the size is still fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have already discovered you can just re-make your own avatar to fit the hat, I say the devs should add a template to the Winter Bash FAQ instead!

That way you can see how to best fit any avatar to all the beautiful hats.

I for one, will not be remaking mine. I like my cupcake-head ninja puppet! Or my handsome fez ninja!

[image: cupcake ninja]
[image: fez ninja]

Comment: Yea, that would be useful ^_^

Comment: Wow that cake fits **flawlessly**! you should take screenshot and show your grandchildren when the time comes. :-D Oh, and it's a secret hat.. nice!