# Counter vote the closure of a question

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

Let's say that there is a question that 40 people consider a real question.

But 5 people consider it not a real question and they can vote, so they vote to close it.That 40 people should wait that the question closes to reopen it.But why not giving the power to vote against the closure of a question?

For example 40 people (the OP can't self-vote) vote to don't close it, 5 people vote to close it so it's +35. It will be closed only if other 40 people vote to close it. All this with all the variants that may come, for example a closure vote may have a higher value than a counter-closure vote.

I think that isn't acceptable that the question in this case has to be closed and reopened.Afterall if many people are interested in the question, and they're giving answers, why closing it? Is that not a real question even if 40 people have understood the question and they're answering to it?

Comment: (As an aside, please read about [the difference between a paragraph and a line break](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a question was closed, you can vote to reopen it.

Add a comment as to *why* you think it should be reopened, then cast your vote. It'll be added to the Reopen Votes review queue, and if enough people agree, it'll be reopened.

The Close Votes review queue *already* lets you vote to leave it open:

[image: Leave Open option]

If enough people (== 3) vote for leaving it open, it'll be removed from the vote queue altogether. Note also that close votes expire at 1 vote every 4 days of inactivity (only on questions with more than a 100 views).

We do *not* need more voting to complicate matters. Yes, there sometimes is a 'accidental' close as robo reviewers follow the herd, but reopens are rare enough that it usually doesn't take long for an accidental close to be reversed.

Comment: (That hat fits you well, Martijn `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan: My ninja is an awesome hat bearer. You should [see the cupcake](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159335/can-we-resize-hats/159339#159339) on it's shoulders! :-)

Comment: "The Close Votes review queue already let's you vote to leave it open", how?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: By clicking on `Leave Open` as now illustrated in my answer.

Comment: On stack overflow I don't have this button.I have share,edit, close(reopen if it's closed) flag.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: I am talking about the *review queues*, not the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this happens a lot that 5 different people vote to close a question that should not be.

In that rare cases you can try to argue with the "closers" through comments.

Comment: Ok but say that 1000 people visit the question, and they all can vote.5 by 1000 it's still few.

Comment: If 5 people with 3k+ rep cast close votes then it is 99.9% close-worthy.

Comment: Cast reopen, I know.But I'm talking about counter-close vote.