# Change the hats size

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013

So this is my first time with the hats. It's fun.

Maybe it would be possible to be able to change the hat size so that you can "fit" it to your profile picture?

I realize that this is likely not possible in the short time left of this promotion, but maybe next year.

---

I also know that there is [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159335/can-we-resize-hats), but I want to specifically focus on resizing.