# Is this the first Winter Bash? And can one adjust the position of hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

It's nice that SO offers this cute little feature called Winter Bash as you all might have notice.

I am only a new user so my question here is to the old timers:

Did you guys use to have something similar in this past Winters? Or is this the first time ever?

My another question here is: is it possible to submit a request for this feature, a feature that allows the user to at least drag and move around the Hat Image over one's profile picture a little bit as to adjust the hat position?

It would be nice, because some of the users I have seen with hats have their hats positioned in a way it covers the eyes or partially of them, which reminds me of Audrey Hepburn's Image in "Breakfast' at Tiffany's".

Happy Holidays to everyone.

Comment: As an aside, for future questions you might ask: even on Meta we'd like *one* question per question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the second Winter Bash, we had one last year too: See https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash and [winterbash-2012](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2012).

Other [promotions](https://stackexchange.com/promos) in the past were limited to one site or were marketing promotions for 3rd parties.

You can **already** adjust the hat position. Select a hat, then use your mouse to adjust the position just right:

[image][image]

Comment: Super, Happy Holidays to everyone who happens to see this post.

Comment: (Remember how last year some hats [fitted so well for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159335/can-we-resize-hats/159339#159339)? This year it looks nice too. That's one good avatar you have there!)

Comment: @Arjan: Oh, [I definitely remember](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash/161189#161189). :-)

Comment: I guess the team used your ninja when designing that eagle :-)