# Manually customize position of Winter Bash hats

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow more specific positioning of hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159149/allow-more-specific-positioning-of-hats)
>   [Can we resize hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159335/can-we-resize-hats)

I really like the idea of [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/). But unfortunately all the hats I have do not fit on my picture :(

It would be really cool and nice if we can drag the hat and manually adjust the position of hat?

Comment: You could just take a new picture like many people have already done.

Comment: I tried to find that question but couldn't find it. Sorry!

Comment: It is a genuine question though, if it is already been asked what is the purpose of down vote? sometimes its hard to find if the question is already been asked or not :/

Comment: Sometimes a little bit of research could avoid duplicate questions. Some other times people just downvote unpopular question for no reason without comments i know it sucks. Personally i'm against downvoting for duplicates question but it's just my opinion

Comment: I am agree with you @PhaDaPhunk [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159149/allow-more-specific-positioning-of-hats) has 9 votes, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159335/can-we-resize-hats) has 4 votes, both are identical. And I am receiving down votes :)

Comment: Come on, man! We can't just code up whatever feature you happen to want at the drop of a hat!

Comment: Now possible, see my answer on [Allow more specific positioning of hats?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211798)

Answer (score 0):

The best bet for you right now would be to customize your own profile picture to get it aligned with the hat. I don't see anything in the near future happening in the direction you requested to let users drop the hat where they want.